# Insert/Update functionality in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update

i'm manually updating table in my DB using import functionality in PostgreSQL. Working with large number of data i came across an issue of duplicating primary keys. I am looking for a script to upload only values that do not violate primary key assumption, and those that to violate are to be ignored (not uploaded or updated).

I have already seen a code that would kind of do what i need however not quite sure if it will work for me.

Columns i am working with are:
acc_ph_id (primary_key);acc_ph_no;ph_type;ph_flag

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated as i am rather new to Postgresql in general.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the table into a staging table with no constraints.

Then load the table into the full table eliminating duplicates:

```
insert into real_table(acc_ph_id, acc_ph_no, ph_type, ph_flag)
    select distinct on (acc_ph_id) acc_ph_id, acc_ph_no, ph_type, ph_flag
    from staging_table
    order by acc_ph_id;
```

EDIT:

Oh, if the problem is the keys that already exist, then do:

```
insert into real_table(acc_ph_id, acc_ph_no, ph_type, ph_flag)
    select distinct on (acc_ph_id) acc_ph_id, acc_ph_no, ph_type, ph_flag
    from staging_table st
    where not exists (select 1
                      from real_table rt
                      where rt.acc_ph_id = st.acc_ph_id
                     )
    order by acc_ph_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will this work in case if there are not duplicate primary keys in staging_table but somewhere between staging_table and real_table? thanks

Comment: That is correct, there are primary keys in "real_table" that are also present in the "staging_table". Thanks alot for you prompt response. I'll try your solution and will update this post.

Comment: Strongly recommend a `LOCK TABLE` in the transaction doing this work.